# eclipse-betaupdate not found?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have an installtion of Eclipse Indigo, service release 2. When I attempt to get the updates I get the following error:

No repository found at http://home.zingo.org/eclipse-betaupdate/.

I notice that it says betadate so I guess that there have been a change in url? Do I need to reinstall Eclipse?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not fix the problem so I reinstalled and now it seems to work as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

You should endeavour to use official update sites. Offsite mirrors may be taken down at any time. See [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites) for a list of update sites. You can do this via the [Update Manager](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_Update_Manager%3F).